# Bootstrap panel/button with no border

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I eliminate the surrounding borderline of a bootstrap panel or button in html? Colouring the panel/button with a contextual class does not help because there is no such class that matches my background colour. Example code I am using is the standard code on bootstrap's js page like [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example) for the button and [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) for the panel.

Comment: How about showing the code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer, just use inside the `class` of the button `btn-link` which replaces the button with a link, thus removing the borders. An example code follows:

```
<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"     data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false"     aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Button with data-target
</button>
 <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
   <div class="well">
     ...
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need used:

```
style="border: 0 !important;"
```

See [Bootply without border and shading](http://www.bootply.com/yA4FvRDrjZ)

I hope can help you, Good luck!

Comment: the chosen answer makes a different point because -link adds other link behaviors. this answers the question.